# Windows 10 not responsing on USB connectting

Tags: windows, usb

I have 2 Windows Computers, and both are not responding on USB Connecting. The USB is a Sandisk 32 GB USB 3.0 stick, and there are important files on it. How can I access to it? If i connect it, i cannot launch programs, open menu, i cannot do anything. Thanks

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you mean it doesn't open Windows Explorer? Press the Windows key and the E key at the same time to open Explorer.

Comment: Golden rules: #1 Never… repeat ***never*** store the only copy of any data in one place, especially not on a removable USB stick/SD card. They have amazingly high fail rates. #2 Any data stored in less than three distinct locations ought to be considered temporary.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like it might have died. Open Device Manager & watch for it to flash/reload when plugging it in, if it doesn't & you don't get an audible sound that confirms it's bad. Very unlikely two PC's are bad. You can try to call SanDisk for warranty, but they are unlikely to help get your files back sadly :(

Comment: Oh no. If I unplug it, and open Device Manager and plug it in, I can click reload, but It is not working.

Comment: Is there no way to get the files?

Comment: USB flash drives are recognized as having a failure rate much higher than HDDs and SSDs. https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk may, repeat may, be able to find files and directories on it.